# Compare array positions from the middle of his string

Tags: php, html, arrays, compare, html-table

Anyone knows how to compare all the array elements but only from the middle of every element? I'll try to explain myself. Here is the dump from the array and in bold(**), the string part to compare with every array element:

```
array(3) {
[0]=> string(182) "<tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>**<td>Column4</td><td>Column5</td><td>Column6</td><td>Column7</td><td>Column8</td><td>Column9</td><td>Column10</td><td> </td></tr>**"

[1]=> string(182) "<tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>**<td>Column4</td><td>Column5</td><td>Column6</td><td>Column7</td><td>Column8</td><td>Column9</td><td>Column10</td><td> </td></tr>**"

[2]=> string(182) "<tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>**<td>Column4</td><td>Column5</td><td>Column6</td><td>Column7</td><td>Column8</td><td>Column9</td><td>Column10</td><td> </td></tr>**"
}
```

I don't want to compare the entire string, only the bold part to see if it matches between its array elements. If there is two array elements with the same part, then, one must be deleted.

Comment: Am I getting this right; you want to remove all rows from the array, where a part of the value matches the same part of another array value?

Comment: @mhall thanks a lot for your response. Yes, you get it!! I don't know if It's possible, or if I need to create another array (multiarray?) to separate every cell. But then, I think it would be more difficult to compare a lot of cells : \

Comment: Step 1: What is the logic for identifying where to start comparing? The computer cannot comprehend "Right there in the middle-ish". You need to clearly define it such as "After the third occurrence of </td>" to the end.

Comment: @kainaw thank you! Yes, the logic is "after the third occurrence of </td>". I didn't know how to say it in php.

Comment: @Paculop You can, on the fly, remove everything up to the third </td> with a regular expression. This is not the fastest way to do it, but it should be very understandable: preg_replace('/^<tr><td>[^<]*</td><td>[^<]*</td><td>[^*]</td>/','',$string); That will replace all up to the third <td> with an empty string. Now, you can use that preg_replace on to string values to see of what is left is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$array = array(
    "<tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td><td>Column4 Foo</td></tr>",
    "<tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td><td>Column4 Bar</td></tr>",
    "<tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td><td>Column4 Foo</td></tr>",
);

// Array of values (interesting part of) already seen
$alreadyInArray = array();

// Filter out duplicates
$array = array_filter(
    $array,
    function($val) use (&$alreadyInArray) {
        // Get everything "after the third occurrence of </td>"
        preg_match('#(?:.*?</td>){3}(.*)$#', $val, $matches);
        $partToCheck = $matches[1];

        // Have we seen this value before?
        if (isset($alreadyInArray[$partToCheck]))
            return false; // Duplicate - leave out of array

        // Not seen before, keep and add value to check array
        $alreadyInArray[$partToCheck] = true;
        return true;
    }
);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td><td>Column4 Foo</td></tr>
    [1] => <tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td><td>Column4 Bar</td></tr>
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's possible to ignore white spaces in the preg_match? I'm experiencing some problems because there are a lot of white spaces or double white spaces in the original array. I've removed all the white spaces with str_replace and worked fine, but when I print the results white spaces are lost and the text is unreadable :S

Comment: Sure, just add a `$partToCheck = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $partToCheck);` below the `$partToCheck = $matches[1];` line.

Comment: you're a guru man! It is by far the fastest response I've ever received. And worked like a charm! I'm very impressed.

And very grateful. Once again, thank you so much!!!!!